# Display Factor Variable Data into Table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

This is the small sampleData of half million rows,here product,date and salesamount is a factor variable.
I need to divide the data by year 2011 and 2012 and display the product with its total sum of the sales amount in that year.
I tried a lot at last i did it in excel using pivot table. 
but i want know that how this can be achived in R, as i don't want more excel files.
Thankyou

```
 product    date       salesamount
   a       2011-01          35
   b       2011-02          40
   c       2011-03          50
   d       2011-01          55
   b       2012-02          46
   a       2011-02          35
   d       2012-01          62
   c       2012-03          56
   c       2012-02          56
   a       2012-03          38
   b       2012-01          46
   e       2011-03          60
   a       2012-03          38
   e       2012-02          67
   d       2011-01          55
```

Data Should Look something like this after dividing it by year

```
 product   year2011    year2012
   a         70         76
   b         40         92
   c         50         112
   d         110        62
   e         60         67
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a year variable.
2. [Group and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group).
3. [Reshape long to wide.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(date, c('year', 'month')) %>% 
  group_by(product, year) %>% 
  summarise(salesamount = sum(salesamount)) %>% 
  spread(year, salesamount, sep = '')
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
> # Groups:   product [5]
>   product year2011 year2012
>   <chr>      <int>    <int>
> 1 a             70       76
> 2 b             40       92
> 3 c             50      112
> 4 d            110       62
> 5 e             60       67
> ```

Comment: Also `df %>% group_by(product, grp = sub('-.*', '', date)) %>% summarise(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
DT[, year:=substr(date, 1, 4)]
dcast(DT, product ~ year, value.var="salesamount", fun.aggregate = sum)
# > dcast(DT, product ~ year, value.var="salesamount", fun.aggregate = sum)
#    product 2011 2012
# 1:       a   70   76
# 2:       b   40   92
# 3:       c   50  112
# 4:       d  110   62
# 5:       e   60   67
```

**Data:**

```
DT <- fread(
" product    date       salesamount
   a       2011-01          35
   b       2011-02          40
   c       2011-03          50
   d       2011-01          55
   b       2012-02          46
   a       2011-02          35
   d       2012-01          62
   c       2012-03          56
   c       2012-02          56
   a       2012-03          38
   b       2012-01          46
   e       2011-03          60
   a       2012-03          38
   e       2012-02          67
   d       2011-01          55")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dat object is `dat` then the base `tapply` approach would be:

```
with( dat, tapply( salesamount, list( product, substring(date, 1,4) ), sum) )
  2011 2012
a   70   76
b   40   92
c   50  112
d  110   62
e   60   67
```